# Controlling a Mac Mini from Linux Mint - Some special keys don't work

Tags: keyboard, remote-desktop, mint, teamviewer, mac-mini

I've installed TeamViewer on 2 machines: my ASUS X555-LD laptop running Linux Mint Cinnamon 17.3 and a late-2012 Mac Mini running OS X El Capitan. The task is to remote control the Mac with the ASUS laptop's Linux Mint. After connection is set **and** the *"Action > Send key combinations"* option is enabled, there are still some remaining issues with special keys:

- My laptop's "*Windows*" key doesn't trigger the "*Command*" key on Mac; instead, the Linux Mint dock menu opens, like I would not even using TeamViewer
- My laptop's "*Caps Lock*" key doesn't seem to work at all on Mac
- My laptop's "*AltGr*" key triggers the "a" character's key on Mac before triggering the character / function I wanted; for example, if I try to type a semicolon (;) it types "a;" instead

Every other main special keys ("Alt", "Tab", "Ctrl", "Shift") are working normally. Does / Did anybody have this kind of problem, too?

Comment: We only support official versions of Ubuntu.  Use http://unix.stackexchange.com/ for unofficial versions.